# How do we set the tab names which works across all browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, tabs

I see the document.title sets the tab names on IE but it does not seem to work on FF. Not tried with Chrome. Is there a way that will enable to set the tab name on all the types of browsers

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `document.title` also works on Firefox and Chrome. 
Are you trying to set a title before the document is fully loaded? If so, try setting a title after the document is loaded.